# How to scp from server to server with different public keys?

Tags: scp

What arguments would I use for the `scp` command on a server to server copy if the two servers need different ssh keys? I know how to scp files from a server to a server without having data flow on the PC (the one from which I issued the `scp` command).

Based on [this tutorial](https://varrunr.wordpress.com/2009/05/18/scp-copy-fromto-remote-server-with-ssh/), my starting command looks something like this:

```
scp -r miguel@10.1.2.2:/home/miguel/ miguel@10.1.2.3:/home/miguel/
```

Comment: I would question your statement that `scp`ing from one remote host to another using a third machine to issue the command doesn't transfer data over the wire to your local PC to and from the remotes. Are you sure about that or is this just a convenience command for what gets run as a two step process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [ssh-agent](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-agent) and [ssh-add](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-add) all the keys you need to it.

Example:

```
# start the agent and capture its environment in the current shell
eval `ssh-agent`

# add keys needed to connect to the different accounts
ssh-add /path/to/first/ssh/key
ssh-add /path/to/second/ssh/key

# do the copying
scp first@host1.example.com:file1 second@host2.example.com:file2
```

Comment: is this working?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I was wrong about the transfer through localhost. The manual I read didn't clarify it.

You have to setup a key pair for authentication from server1 to server2. So, you must be able to connect from your system to server1 and from server1 to server2.
You effectively run `ssh user@server1 scp -r files user@server2:files`