# scp between two servers with different pem files

Tags: scp

I'm following the answer on [How to scp from server to server with different public keys?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15647/how-to-scp-from-server-to-server-with-different-public-keys) but I'm getting a connection error:

```
# start the agent and capture its environment in the current shell
eval `ssh-agent`

# add keys needed to connect to the different accounts
ssh-add /path/to/first/ssh/key
ssh-add /path/to/second/ssh/key

# do the copying

$ scp -r user@server1:/images user@server2:/images
ssh: connect to host server2 port 22: Connection timed out
lost connection
```

It works if I use my machine as an explicit intermediary:

```
$ scp -r user@server1:/images /images
$ scp -r /images user@server2:/images
```

Any clues on why it's failing to do the copy in one step?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A remote-to-remote `scp` actually works by logging into the first machine using `ssh`, and running `scp` from there. So, basically, server1 can't connect to server2 (presumably, due to a firewall rule).

You can add the `-3` option to route the copy through your local machine, avoiding the above issue. The documentation for OpenSSH 6.5 at least warns that you'll not get a progress meter.

(Note: `scp` didn't used to do remote-to-remote transfers; one side was required to be local. So this is a somewhat new feature.)